# k8s cluster pod terminates process

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

in K8S cluster we can define resource limit and once application reached to limit k8S cluster will automatically terminates this container and brings new one. There can be other reason as well for a pod to get terminated. Wanted to know  1) what happens to those transaction that are in mid of processing  & 2) If have one replica only is all incoming request get stopped before another one start up.

Can anyone help to understand this in more details?

Thanks
Baharul Islam

Answer (score 0):

Try adding grafana in your kubernetes cluster and check the memory POD is requiring while you are doing the load test ( or just the case that you are taking now), if it reaches the limits, then try increasing the memory and cpu limit assigned to it.

I faced one scenario where Pod was supposed to carry some data from database and the resources were not appropriate when data was high and the call used to fail by giving 500 kinda error and multiple Pods were there alive at that time in picture, still there was drop in response.

Then I checked for grafana and it had shown that large memory limits should be set, and after doing it, the things were sorted.

You should try debugging this way, maybe helps.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. But my question is not this. I am asking what will happen to those transaction that server was already processing (maybe server was processing 100+ requests and issue happen with 1 particular scenerio) what will happen to those running transaction?

Comment: Well, am not much clear at that part yet, as I am also looking to figure out such scenarios, maybe you can check for the data populated in the respective tables and if there was a drop in few of them, then one can deduce something on that